# how to access a private values from the super class in Java?

Tags: java

I want to access two private variables from the superclass `MathProblem`, but I don't know how to access them. I know that the private things are not inherited, but I need those two variable to access them and add them and return the value.

```
abstract public class MathProblem {
    private int operand1;
    private int operand2;
    private int userAnswer;

    public MathProblem() {
        operand1 = RandomUtil.nextInt(99);
        operand2 = RandomUtil.nextInt(99);
    }

    public int getOperand1() {
        return operand1;
    }

    public void setOperand1(int operand1) {
        this.operand1 = operand1;
    }

    public int getOperand2() {
        return operand2;
    }

    public void setOperand2(int operand2) {
        this.operand2 = operand2;
    }

    public int getUserAnswer() {
        return userAnswer;
    }

    public void setUserAnswer(int userAnswer) {
        this.userAnswer = userAnswer;
    }
}
```

And the sub class is like this:

```
public class AdditionMathProblem extends MathProblem {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public AdditionMathProblem() {
        super();
        // can't access the private values.
    }

    @Override
    public int getAnswer() {    
        int result = getOperand1() + getOperand2();
        return result;
    }
}
```

So in class `AdditionMathProblem`, I used the `getOperand1() + getOperand2()` to add the two values, but I need those two values letter to access them. So my question is: **Is there any way I can access them?**

Comment: You've defined `public` `get/set` methods for the operands; why can't you use them to access the values?

Comment: im gonna need the values letter.

Comment: If you have getters and setters for both operands, why would you need to access the field directly?

Comment: The getters and setters actually give you everything you would need so you haven't really explained to us what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `protected` access modifier instead of `private`. This will allow subclasses to access the members of their base class.

Comment: Clearly the best thing to do, but since the OP didn't say that the original class was modifiable, I came up with a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You cant access private variables directly from outside its class. If you would like that variable to be accessible by its parent then you can:

1. Change modifier from private to protected. 
   Or
2. If you want the variable to remain private then you can create a publec method that returns that variable. Then from the child class just call that method.